# Causes of hanging?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, lenovo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I never experienced any hanging on my old laptop, but on my new laptop Ubuntu 12.04 hangs all the time. The screen freezes and all the indicator lights on my laptop stop blinking The only thing I can do is a cold reboot.

My laptop is Lenovo U310, 64-bit with 30G SSD (used only for Intel RST under a Windows 7 installation). I don't quite remember how the raid stuff was configured when I installed my Ubuntu, but I'm sure my Ubuntu does not use the SSD.

I realize that the freezing is more likely to occur under slightly higher CPU load. (like when I open a resource-consuming web page or so, but it doesn't always occur)

What are the possible causes of freezing that I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely run the memory checker - it is a boot option.
The other cause is usually the display driver.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is HDD issues. My laptop was freezing like yours before my HDD death.

You can try the window's scandisk option (since you have W7 installed). Of couse, the memory check mentioned before is something you should also try, just to be sure :)

Thanks,
Seb.